# Creating Dataframe from Dictionary of Lists, ignoring keys

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, dataframe

i have dictionary of lists that looks like this

```
d = {'key1':['banana','apple','mango'],
     'key2':['banana','orange'],
     'key3':['apple','melon','orange','mango']}
```

Now, I want to create Dataframe from it. The dataframe must look like this

```
 'banana' | 'apple'  | 'mango' | NaN
 'banana' | 'orange' |   NaN   | NaN
 'apple'  | 'melon'  | 'orange'|'mango'
```

Comment: why you delete the other question ? what was the issue ?

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`from_dict`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.from_dict.html) with `orient='index'`:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index')
```

```
           0       1       2      3
key1  banana   apple   mango   None
key2  banana  orange    None   None
key3   apple   melon  orange  mango
```

If you want a numeric index:

```
pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').reset_index(drop=True)
```

```
        0       1       2      3
0  banana   apple   mango   None
1  banana  orange    None   None
2   apple   melon  orange  mango
```

Comment: and how do i replace only the 'None' values with NaN?

Comment: `None` is treated similarly to `NaN`, if you'd prefer NaN just use `pd.DataFrame.from_dict(d, orient='index').fillna(np.nan)`

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
d = {'key1':['banana','apple','mango'],
     'key2':['banana','orange'],
     'key3':['apple','melon','orange','mango']}

>>> pd.DataFrame(list(d.values()))

    0       1       2       3
0   banana  apple   mango   None
1   banana  orange  None    None
2   apple   melon   orange  mango
```

Comment: Not sure why you'd want to to this. But just do `df.fillna(np.nan)`